# Error while uploading a database in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, php

I am getting this error while i am trying to upload a database that is 1.9 mb size and i have increased the upload size to 750 MiB , upload_time to 5000 in my php.ini file , but i am getting this error now , how can i remove this error and successfully upload the database from phpmyadmin.

"
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 500
localhost
Tue Jun 26 14:38:04 2012
Apache/2.2.21 (Linux/SUSE) "

Any help will be appreciated, Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max_post_size` in php.ini?

If not, and you have ssh access,  just use the cli tools:

http://www.techiecorner.com/44/how-to-backup-mysql-database-in-command-line-with-compression/